# Relationship Between Free Group Actions of a Finite Set

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, group-homomorphism

(Similar to the above question, but unfortunately I could not see where to go with the above hint. I'm sure it's obvious, but right now I feel that I am missing the point - even just a hint giving a small explanation would be appreciated.)

> We say that a group, $G$, acts freely on a set S if for any non-trivial $g \in G$, and any $s \in S$, we have $g · s = s$. Let $φ(g, s) = g · s$ and $ψ(g, s) = g ∗ s$ be two free actions of a finite group G on a finite set S. Show that there is a function $f : S → S$ such that
>   $$f(g · s) = g ∗ f(s)$$
>   for all $g ∈ G, s ∈ S$.

I am able to prove this in the case that $G$ is cyclic, but not otherwise. I am thinking that a possible way forward might be to consider the orbits of $S$ as we can see (from the Orbit-Stabiliser theorem, for example) that each orbit of $S$ has the same size for both actions; at this point I am just confusing myself though, and I would appreciate any hints on how to proceed.

Comment: Let $I$ be the set of orbits of $\varphi$, and let $\{ \alpha_i : i \in I \}$ be a  representatives of these orbits. Choose any $\beta \in X$, and define $f$ by $f(g \cdot \alpha_i) = g*\beta$ for all $i \in I$ and $g \in G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you for your hint Derek. I am really sorry though, but I am not sure I follow (please don't think I am too stupid!) Where does $\beta$ come into use, and in the definition of $f$, what is the $\alpha$ on the RHS? Also, if you don't mind, could you just give a bit of explanation on how this would solve the problem (not because I doubt that it does, but just because I am having a hard time putting 2 and 2 together). I you give an explanation as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks. **Edit:** Sorry, just saw you modified your comment!

Comment: Firstly note that  for every $s \in S$ there exists a unique $g \in G$ and $i \in I$ with $s = g \cdot \alpha_i$, so $f$ is well-defined. Now you just have to check the condition $f(g \cdot s) = g*f(s)$ for all $s \in S$ and $g \in G$ so try and do that.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you for the hint / extended explanation. I will try to do this, and I think I see the overall idea now. If you post your hints as a solution, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: @DerekHolt I understand how this works now, but I would really appreciate if you could possibly provide some of the intuition that leads to this result. That is, how did you reach this solution? What 'picture' motivates this definition of $f$?

Comment: I can't post the hints as a solution because the question has been closed as a duplicate. It is identical to the previous question, not just similar.

Comment: @DerekHolt OK I accept that. What is the official policy when the answer to a question is very far from what you need? Are you just expected to leave a comment and just hope that someone revisits the question to respond. For example, of a question is poorly answered, does this effectively shut it off from ever being re-asked with the hope of a better solution - I feel that simply leaving a comment on an answer requesting elaboration rarely results in a response.

Comment: I don't know the official policy. But it now has four reopen votes, so if it is reopened then I will post  a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I$ be the set of orbits of the action $\varphi$ of $G$ on $S$, and let $\{ \alpha_i : i \in I \}$ be a set of representatives of the se orbits. Since the action is free, for each $s \in S$, there exists a unique $i \in I$ and $h \in G$ such that $h \cdot \alpha_i = s$.

Now, choose any $\beta \in S$ and define $f:S \to S$ by $f(h \cdot \alpha_i) = h * \beta$. By the uniqueness property above, this defines $f(s)$ uniquely for each $s \in S$.

We have to check that $f(g \cdot s) = g * f(s)$ for all $g \in G$ and $s \in S$. By the above, we can write each $s \in S$ as $h \cdot \alpha_i$ for some $i \in I$ and $h \in G$. Then
$$f(g \cdot s) = f(g.(h \cdot \alpha_i)) = f((gh) \cdot \alpha_i) = (gh) * \alpha = g*(h* \alpha) = g*f(h \cdot \alpha) =\hbox{$  g*f(s)$}.$$